# Arabic Date on Android App

Tags: java, android, date

I'm working on android app , and the next release to add Arabic language on the app , but i have a problem .

this problem is : the Android OS convert the date **dynamically** to Arabic format , and i used it in URL parameter, and the server can't read it .

How can i convert any Arabic date to English date ?!?

**what the Android OS show me : ١٤-٠٥-٢٠١٤**
**What i need is : 2014-05-14**

I tired some Java lines like this :

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

And Android doesn't has the Locale.Arabic format

**The problem appears when you convert your phone into Arabic Language**

Comment: didn't `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.ENGLISH);` work?

Comment: no , did't work , I"m very surprised , it must work :(

Comment: @njzk2 i found the solution :D
i must do this 
SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: @MhmdAljobairi Could you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: @SoH the problem was i put the format from left to right , and the arabic langauge need to put it from right to left for every date ,

`SimpleDateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");`

`SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

Your desired format happens to be defined in the ISO 8601 standard. The *java.time* classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating text.

```
LocalDate.now().toString()
```

> 2019-01-23

To localize to [English in the United States](http://www.localeplanet.com/java/en-US/):

```
LocalDate
.now(
    ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) 
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(
        FormatStyle.FULL   // or LONG or MEDIUM or SHORT
    )
    .withLocale(  
        new Locale( "en" , "US" )   // English language, with cultural norms of United States. 
    )
)
```

For [Arabic in Tunisia](http://www.localeplanet.com/java/ar-TN/index.html), use:

```
new Locale( "ar" , "TN" )
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using the terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. They were supplanted entirely by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. For earlier Android, see bullets at bottom below.

## `Locale`

> And Android doesn't has the Locale.Arabic format

Only a few of the many locales have a named constant. Learn to specify a `Locale` by the standard language code and country (culture) code, as explained in the [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) class. For more info, see [this related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20844525/642706).

For example, for [Arabic language with Saudi Arabia cultural norms](http://www.localeplanet.com/java/ar-SA/index.html), use:

```
Locale locale = new Locale( "ar" , "SA" ) ;  // Arabic language. Saudi Arabia cultural norms.
```

We can use that locale to localize the text representing a moment.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" );  // By the way, time zone has *nothing* to do with locale, orthogonal issues.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
Locale locale = new Locale( "ar" , "SA" );
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( locale );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

When run.

> الجمعة، 18 يناير 2019 12:14:00 م توقيت نيوزيلندا الصيفي

To see all the locale definitions available on your system, run this code.

```
    for ( Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales() ) {
        System.out.println( locale.toString() + "  Name: " + locale.getDisplayName( Locale.US ) );
    }
```

## Today's date in English

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Ditto for [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) & [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

To generate text localized to English, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate`.

```
FormatStyle formatStyle = FormatStyle.FULL ;
Locale locale = new Locale( "en" , "US" ) ; // English language, United States cultural norms.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( formatStyle ).withLocale( locale );
String output = localDate.format( f ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is working

val formatterNew = SimpleDateFormat(requiredFormat,Locale.forLanguageTag("ar"))

Comment: The OP has asked for a JAVA solution, yours is in Kotlin. I am voting to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use below code for get date in ENGLISH language in localization.

```
   Date currentDate = new Date();
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
   System.out.println(sdf.format(currentDate));
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).