# How to store file with date into SD card?

Tags: java, android, android-date

In my application I want store a file into SD card.
What I would like is that when the app stores this file, add the now date as filename and for this I wrote the below codes.

But when users change the device language to **UTF-8** languages (such as : **Farsi** - **Arabic** , ...) the file is stored with **UTF-8** characters!

**For example :** store file with this name : `COM_MyVideo_۲۰۲۰-۱-۵`
but i want store with this name : `COM_MyVideo_2020-1-5`

**My codes:**

```
private String getFileSaveName() {
    videoName = GoodPrefs.getInstance().getString(ConstKeys.TEST_NAME, "MyApp");
    videoName = videoName + "-" + GoodPrefs.getInstance().getInt(ConstKeys.TEST_ID, 0) + "-";
    String filename = "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss";
    //Required to handle preference change
    filename = filename.replace("hh", "HH");
    String prefix = "COM_" + videoName;
    Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(filename);
    return prefix + formatter.format(today);
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612392/arabic-date-on-android-app

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try his , first create the current datetime as a timestamp, after convert the timestamp into a local english date, and format it as you need.

```
 Date date= new Date();

 long time = date.getTime();

 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    cal.setTimeInMillis(time * 1000);
    String date = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", cal).toString();
```